# ValueError: The `index` argument must be one-dimensional (got 2 dimensions)

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, valueerror, pytorch-geometric

receiving the following error:

```
ValueError: The `index` argument must be one-dimensional (got 2 dimensions)
```

while using RGCN model of pyTorch:

```
output = rgcn_layer(x = x, edge_index = edge_index, edge_type = edge_type)
```

You may read the documentation from: https://pytorch-geometric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/torch_geometric.nn.conv.RGCNConv.html

The value of edge_index is appearing to be correct i.e one dimensional tensor. Head: `tensor([20, 12, 50, 38, 64])`

I do not understand why it is refusing to accept the tensor shown above. Is there something wrong with the library, considering it is newly implemented?